# Firebase Two-Factor Authentication with Typescript: Error (auth/argument-error)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have followed the code from the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor#signing_users_in_with_a_second_factor). When you scroll down to the full code, it has two things that make problems. First of all, this seems weird:

```
const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container-id', undefined, auth);
const auth = getAuth();
```

They define `auth` **after** using it for `recaptchaVerifier`. But that seems like a typo, so I just switched these two lines.

But I cannot resolve the second issue. Their code is in JavaScript, my code is in TypeScript. They use `undefined` as an argument in the definition of `recaptchaVerifier`:

`const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container-id', undefined, auth);`

The second argument of the constructor is `undefined`. Since TypeScript does not allow that, I tried many things, for example these:

1. `const undef: any = undefined; const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container-id', undef, auth);`
2. `const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container-id', { size: 'invisible' }, auth);`

But it ALWAYS gives this error in the console:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
    at createErrorInternal (index-0bb4da3b.js:474:41)
    at _assert (index-0bb4da3b.js:480:15)
    at new RecaptchaVerifier (index-0bb4da3b.js:7369:9)
```

I could not find anything that helped me fix this error in the internet.

---

Here is my full code:

```
LogIn(email: string, password: string) {
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    const undef: any = undefined;
    const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      'recaptcha-container-id',
      undef,
      auth
    );

    /* It never reaches this code below here since new RecaptchaVerifier() always throws an error */

    
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
          }
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code == 'auth/multi-factor-auth-required') {
          // The user is a multi-factor user. Second factor challenge is required.
          const auth = getAuth();
          let resolver = getMultiFactorResolver(auth, error);

          const phoneInfoOptions = {
            multiFactorHint: resolver.hints[0],
            session: resolver.session
          };

          // Send SMS verification code.
          const phoneAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);

          phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, recaptchaVerifier)
              .then((verificationId) => {
                  // verificationId will be needed for sign-in completion.
                  
                  // Ask user for the SMS verification code via prompt (yeah, very bad UI)
                  const verificationCode = prompt("Enter the verification code we sent to your number");
                  
                  if (verificationCode !== null) {
                    const cred = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
                    const multiFactorAssertion = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(cred);

                    // Complete sign-in.
                    return resolver.resolveSignIn(multiFactorAssertion);

                  } else {
                    this.toast.error("Entered wrong code");
                    return null;
                  }
              })
              .then((userCredential) => {
                // User successfully signed in with the second factor phone number.
                this.toast.success("Code is correct. Logged in");
                this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
                  if (user) {
                    this.router.navigate(['home']);
                  }
                });

              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
    
                // failed
                this.toast.error(error.message);
              });

        } else if (error.code == 'auth/wrong-password') {
          this.toast.error(error.message);
        }
      });
  }
```

I am using Angular and angularfire. The code above is not called directly from a component, but from a service. That service though is called from my LoginComponent.

---

Edit. My imports are:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { child, get, getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { HotToastService } from '@ngneat/hot-toast';
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { getAuth, getMultiFactorResolver, GoogleAuthProvider, PhoneAuthProvider, PhoneMultiFactorGenerator, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
```

Comment: Can you share your imports?

Comment: Can you share your HTML to validate that `recaptcha-container-id` is created?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone I have added the imports. There is HTML related to this because the officials docs I've linked never mention any need for that.

Comment: Yes, you need an empty div with the id passed to the function like `<div id="recaptcha-container-id"></div>`

Comment: This solved it. I checked the docs again. They do mention it, but only in previous sections. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome!. I will answer the question so you can accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked in the comments for this to work you need an empty div with the passed id, like:

`<div id="recaptcha-container-id"></div>`